# Android BLE - Measure traffic from inside application

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, measure, traffic, android-ble

In an android application I want to display the data rate (e.g.: in bytes/second) at which the application (or at least the device) is currently sending data via BLE.

For network traffic there is the android networkStatsManager.
Is there any tool that has similar functionality, but for BLE?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing built into the system. You would have to calculate that yourself for every packet you send or receive.